# Is it bad practice to subscribe to events in a C# Extension Method?

Tags: c#, events, extension-methods

In this case, is it bad to subscribe to the proxy CloseCompleted event?

```
public static void Close(this MyWCFServiceClient proxy)
{
            proxy.CloseCompleted += (o, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                    proxy.Abort();
            };

            proxy.CloseAsync();
}
```

when the proxy is no longer referenced by any code, will it still get garbage collected, or does the event subscription in the extension method hang around holding a reference to proxy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't say it is *bad* practice, but **in the general case** it should probably be obvious that this is going to happen, i.e. clearly documented in the `///` markup. However, in *this* case we are talking about the death of an object - so the caller probably isn't expecting to do much with the object after calling the method. I would also want to make it clear (perhaps in the method name) that this is async.

Re garbage-collection; events keep the **subscriber** alive; not the publisher. If `proxy` is eligible, then it will be collected. The anonymous method doesn't seem to access any captured scope (except for `proxy` itself) - so there is nothing interesting to keep alive anyway (except for the delegate instance itself).

Comment: And what with proxy.Abort()? Proxy here is a parameter of a method, so it's captured by this lambda, therefore a class that will hold reference to proxy object must be created and allocated (after all, it's just a normal method parameter, being an extension method doesn't change anything). Of course it doesn't change anything when it comes to collection, as it will work the same way.

Comment: Oh yes, indeed. You might be able to avoid that by casting the sender, but you're right. And as you say, it won't impact collection anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The proxy has a reference to your anonymous delegate, not vice-versa. Therefore, if no one references the proxy, both it and the anonymous will be cleaned up.